# Text with resources and HTML in TemplateField

Tags: asp.net, gridview, resources, datatemplate, headertext

I nedd to insert a text in resource file with html in the attribute HeaderText of a TemplateField.. I cant use an HeaderTemplate because the sorting does not work... Neither with this [solution](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/5829.aspx) (the datasource result in null).

So im trying a solution like this:

```
HeaderText="<span><%$ Resources:ForumResources, DATA_CREAZIONE %></span><img src="..." />"
```

But it is rendered like this:

```
<span><!-- Resources:ForumResources, DATA_CREAZIONE --></span>
<img src="..." />"
```

Like a comment, why? How can i solve this?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using like this

```
gridview1.Columns[ColumnIndex].HeaderText = "Header text";

gridview1.Columns[ColumnIndex].HeaderText =
                                    Resources:ForumResources, DATA_CREAZIONE;
```

Comment: It has worked finally... thak you very much!!!!!
Id like to know how to do from aspx page... just curiosity... i think it is possible... but it's ok... thanx again

Comment: kindly mark the answer if it helped you. Also I don't know any way of doing it from apsx page.

Answer (score 0):

Call A function that retur string like u want....

DO THIS just  AFTER binding ur gridview

```
gridview1.Columns[ColumnIndex].HeaderText =getstring();

        public string getstring()
        {
        string str="<span>"+yourcontent in the form of string+"</span><img src="..." />";
        return str;
        }
```

Comment: No :( 
Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField does not have a DataBinding event.

I've also tried with <%= instead of <%# but it result in 
    <!-- getstring() -->